# How do I force revert back so a specific revision number using command line SVN?

Tags: svn, trac, svn-update

*I spoke too soon in my previous post about breaking things.*

I am trying to revert back to revision **1124** using the command `svn update -r 1124` but I keep getting an error message as follows:

```
[prague]$ svn update -r1024
U    app/webroot/css/group_themes/green.css
U    app/webroot/css/style.css
Skipped 'app/webroot/index.php'
svn: Failed to add directory 'app/webroot/images/users': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists
```

*We got some stuff back up but still not the exact version which I know I had checked out last night... I thought it would be much easier to just revert back to a specific revision :(*

Comment: Posting the error message might help ...

Comment: btw- I think i hit "svn update 124" right before that so now i just want to force it back to 1124... i have the local copy on my machine but thought i could just "tell" svn to "undo" so to speak

Comment: latest error based on comments below [prague]$ svn update -r 1124
Skipped 'app/webroot/index.php'
svn: Failed to add directory 'app/webroot/images/users': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists
[prague]$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Without commit**

Try to checkout revision 1124 in a new empty directory, so you won't have conflicts with already existing directories.

So `svn checkout -r 1124` in a new directory.

**With commit**

According to the svn manual, if you want to *commit* a previous revision, you need to use reverse merging. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s04.html, 'Undoing Changes'.

`svn merge -c -1124 http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk`
followed by

`svn commit -m "Rollback merge to revision 1124"`

Comment: and once its checked out anew i should be able to just commit version 1124 in the command line?

Comment: Agreed. (Re?)moving the directory works, but using another directory to checkout from altogether might even be easier to do.

Comment: is there a second step... i checked out the new version into a new folder on my local machine... is there a step in between

Comment: i now have a fresh directory on my local- but still cant commit

Comment: latest error based on comments below [prague]$ svn update -r 1124 Skipped 'app/webroot/index.php' svn: Failed to add directory 'app/webroot/images/users': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists [prague]$ – adam 9 mins ago  (sorry i added it to the question not to this thread)

Comment: If checking out a new revision also didn't work, try reverse merging like this: svn merge -c -1124 /path/to/repo and then svn commit. I will update my answer if this works for you.

Comment: but Skipped 'app/webroot/index.php'
svn: Failed to add directory 'app/webroot/images/users': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists
[prague]$

Comment: I updated my answer. Check the link I provided when you want to commit reverted changes, it should work ;).

Comment: i REALLY though we were there it "took" when i got the right url/path but now its asking for a password:)

Comment: Authentication realm: <http://svn.neighborrow.com:80> Private Area
Username: neighborrow
Password for 'neighborrow':
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.neighborrow.com/trac/repos/calc/trunk': authorization failed (http://svn.neighborrow.com)
[prague]$ svn merge -c 1124 http://svn.neighborrow.com/trac/repos/calc/trunk
Authentication realm: <http://svn.neighborrow.com:80> Private Area
Password for 'neighborrow':
Authentication realm: <http://svn.neighborrow.com:80> Private Area
Username: adam
Password for 'adam':
svn: 'http://svn.neighborrow.com/trac/repos/calc/trunk' path not found
[prague]$

Comment: The URL needs to point to your specific repository. The one I provided was just an example. That's why it says: path not found, because the directory doesn't exist. Does it work when you omit the url?

Comment: svn.neighborrow.com/trac IS the repository afaik - i knew to replace the example.com part

Comment: and thanks for being patient- if we dont get it soon my team will probably be up by now to take a look themselves... i just get a kick out of trying to do it myself

Comment: [prague]$ svn merge -c 1124 http://svn.neighborrow.com/trac/calc/trunk
Authentication realm: <http://svn.neighborrow.com:80> Private Area
Password for 'neighborrow':
Authentication realm: <http://svn.neighborrow.com:80> Private Area
Username: adam
Password for 'adam':
svn: 'http://svn.neighborrow.com/trac/calc/trunk' path not found
[prague]$

Comment: didnt catch that extra /repos/ thought that was finally going to do it

Comment: Hmm I'm out of ideas, sorry! I thought it would work because I think I did exactly this to roll back my repo. Update your progress in your question so it gets bumped.

Comment: no apologies needed- i just wanted to see if we could get there! i have my team working on it ill have them post the solution shortly

Answer (score 3):

> Failed to add directory 'app/webroot/images/users': an unversioned directory 
>   of the same name already exists

Sounds clear to me: there already is a directory with that name, and it's not versioned. You can opt for two things: either remove the directory and update again, or rename (probably smartest) and update again.

```
 $ mv app/webroot/images/users app/webroot/images/users.orig/
 $ svn update -r1024
```

As an aside, do yourself a favour and look at some of the alternatives to SVN, such as Mercurial, Bazaar or Git. I've found the switch to be very pleasant ;)

Comment: thanks for the tips... ill definitely try those- i thought SVN/tortoise was my license to mess with code... but all it has done is taken away my fear of breaking things without really making it easy to revert things - even my team who knows this stuff doesnt love it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do an update to revision using

```
svn up -r 1124
```

But this will **not let you commit the changes** as SVN needs you to update your working copy to HEAD before you can commit. What you can do instead is

```
svn merge -r HEAD:1124 yourFile
svn ci yourFile -m "Reverting back to rev 1124 "
```